# Connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I am new to SQL Server. I need to connect to a SQL Server that is running on another machine.

Which tool do I need to install on my Windows 7 laptop to connect remotely?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from Management Studio or from an application? While it can be very laborious, the Command Line SQLCMD.EXE, can be helpful for occasional queries.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server development and administration on a Windows laptop, you can install [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). On MacOS, Linux, or Windows, [SQL Operations Studio (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is) is an option.

Application development may require [separately installed client drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/sql-connection-libraries), which vary by language. ADO.NET is included with the .NET framework, which may already be installed with Windows.